# How to detect multi-touch in sequence?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, multi-touch

I tried to trace multi-touch in sequence, here what I did:

1.Create a cocos2d app
2.Enable multi-touch
3.Add code in touchesBegin:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    for (int i = 0; i < allTouches.count; i++) {

        UITouch *touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
        CGPoint location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]
                                              convertToGL:touchLocation];
        NSLog(@"allTouches %d %0.1f, %0.1f", (i + 1), location.x, location.y);
    }
}
```

I tried the "[touches allObjects]" at first, but that requires the
multi-touch to take place at the same time. What I want here is to
receive multi-touch on at a time. So I used [event allTouches];

4.I tested the code by putting on my finger one at a time, but the
output sequence seems raomdom (first finger with small xVal and second
with big xVal, interval is bigger than 2s):

```
result 1:
2011-03-31 10:54:35.847 MultiTouchDemo[2788:207] allTouches 1 58.0, 458.0
2011-03-31 10:54:38.045 MultiTouchDemo[2788:207] allTouches 1 56.0, 453.0
2011-03-31 10:54:38.046 MultiTouchDemo[2788:207] allTouches 2 930.0, 429.0

result 2:
2011-03-31 10:55:11.659 MultiTouchDemo[2788:207] allTouches 1 86.0, 415.0
2011-03-31 10:55:13.378 MultiTouchDemo[2788:207] allTouches 1 965.0, 409.0
2011-03-31 10:55:13.380 MultiTouchDemo[2788:207] allTouches 2 84.0, 413.0

result 3:
2011-03-31 10:55:32.991 MultiTouchDemo[2788:207] allTouches 1 76.0, 453.0
2011-03-31 10:55:34.630 MultiTouchDemo[2788:207] allTouches 1 877.0, 430.0
2011-03-31 10:55:34.631 MultiTouchDemo[2788:207] allTouches 2 76.0, 455.0

result 4:
2011-03-31 10:55:45.960 MultiTouchDemo[2788:207] allTouches 1 94.0, 440.0
2011-03-31 10:55:47.134 MultiTouchDemo[2788:207] allTouches 1 92.0, 438.0
2011-03-31 10:55:47.136 MultiTouchDemo[2788:207] allTouches 2 934.0, 358.0
```

So you can see the index of the 2nd finger in the [allTouches allObjects]
seems to change all the time.

If I want to make a game support multi-player on a single device,
and I want to trace the move they perform, how could I do this with
all this random pos?

Hope someone can help me, thanks^_^

Answer (score 1):

You could store the touches yourself. On the first call of ccTouchesBegan, store all touches in your list. On subsequent calls, append any touches not already in your list to the end of your list. Then when ccTouchesEnded is called, wipe the list.